# JMeter saving response data - Non-TEXT response data, cannot record: ()

Tags: xml, jmeter

I'm trying to save my response data in a JMeter distributed non-gui test. I'd prefer to be able to do it via the JMeter config, to avoid modifying my custom JMeter controllers and test fragments.

For most of my responses, which are in xml, I get the following response:

```
<responseData class="java.lang.String">Non-TEXT response data, cannot record: ()</responseData>
```

Here are the settings I have in my user.properties:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
# response_data is not currently supported for CSV output
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
# Save ResponseData for failed samples
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=true
```

If this issue is not solvable, I plan to modify my controller to grab the response data with getThreadContext().getPreviousSampler().getResponseDataAsString(), and print this directly to the JMeter log, however, if possible, I'd prefer to do this without changing the code.

Is there any way to get JMeter to convert xml response data and save it to the jtl file, via the config files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jmeter 2.9, response data is stripped when using distributed mode.
This is controlled by mode property which is StrippedBatch bu default.

To get the response, switch it to Batch , but this can impact scalability of JMeter.
You should usually avoid using previous response in your tests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added the code to get the previous response and it works OK. However I will be coding it to only run on the presence of a debug JMeterVariable, so most of the time it will not be used by default.

Is "Batch" mode suitable for a test running on up to 5 agents with hundreds of threads each?

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not the type who doesn't mark answers, I just wanted to clarify things

Comment: thanks :) as a complement you may have to adjust the 2 configuration parameters related to batch mode, mainly interval of time between sends and threshold for send. See in jmeter.properties after mode property for full docd